# I want to make feathersjs listening on 127.0.0.1 (not on 0.0.0.0)

Tags: feathersjs

i want my feathersjs server to listen just to the local address 127.0.0.1.
I tried editing configuration/default.json and changing host to "localhost" and "127.0.0.1"

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3030,
  "public": "../public/",
  "paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 50
  },
```

Though the feathers startup message changes like:

```
info: Feathers application started on http://127.0.0.1:3030
```

No success, server is still listening to 0.0.0.0:3030

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3030                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

please help

Comment: Feathersjs version is 4.5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`src/index.ts/js`](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/crow/src/index.js#L5) change

```
const server = app.listen(port);
```

To [app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback)

```
const server = app.listen(port, host);
```